# Android project debug - LogCat in Eclipse does not display Application info

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am working with an assignment, which asks me to modify an existing project. I have been using Log messages to walk me through the code.
The logging worked fine, until at one point the name of the application was not displayed in the LogCat window any more. 
This is the logcat output, and it is missing the Application information.

> 04-07 16:05:04.065: I/Lab-Threads(7719): Entered installFriendsFragment
>   04-07 16:05:04.075: I/Lab-Threads(7719): Installed Friends Fragment
>   04-07 16:07:59.266: I/Lab-Threads(7972): Entered installFriendsFragment
>   04-07 16:07:59.266: I/Lab-Threads(7972): Installed Friends Fragment
>   04-07 16:13:33.202: I/Lab-Threads(8453): Entered installFriendsFragment
>   04-07 16:13:33.212: I/Lab-Threads(8453): Installed Friends Fragment
>   04-07 16:19:53.933: I/Lab-Threads(8796): Entered installFriendsFragment
>   04-07 16:19:53.933: I/Lab-Threads(8796): Installed Friends Fragment
>   04-07 16:21:47.054: I/Lab-Threads(8968): Entered installFriendsFragment
>   04-07 16:21:47.054: I/Lab-Threads(8968): Installed Friends Fragment
>   04-07 16:26:40.527: I/Lab-Threads(9424): Entered installFriendsFragment
>   04-07 16:26:40.527: I/Lab-Threads(9424): Installed Friends Fragment

This is my first time connecting to a new 2nd gen Nexus 7, but as I said, the Application information was present initially, and I have not done much besides adding new log messages between the different runs.

Do you have any tips what may be going on and how to make sure the Application information is back?

Comment: This has happened to me before. Try switching between filters in the top right corner of the LogCat and end on your packages name after a few switches and the log should show up. Hard to describe it too well without android studio in front of me as I am away from home. Try that and tell me if it works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Get out and get in. Reboot computer and device. I run into something like this all the time. Really no idea how to solve this.